# About iOS Constraint update Animation - Animation block + layoutIfNeeded

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, uiviewanimation

Hello I'm trying to understand view update cycle

I could understand almost things, but there are some mysterious things

I learn that animation blocks are also triggered at update cycle

To try to understand `layoutIfNeeded` in Animation block, I wrote some sample codes like below

```
class MyView: UIView {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        print("Layout Subviews")
    }
}
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var blueHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!

    @IBAction func heightPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        if self.blueHeight.constant == 25.0 {
            self.blueHeight.constant = self.view.bounds.height - 100.0
        } else {
            self.blueHeight.constant = 25.0
        }

        self.view.setNeedsLayout()
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, animations: {
            print("animation block")
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded() // ----- **
        }) { (_) in
            print("animation ended")
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

The output was like this

```
"Layout Subviews"
"Layout Subviews" ---- because of initial settings 
"Animation block"
"Layout Subviews"
"Animation ended"
```

but when i changed `layoutIfNeeded` to `setNeedsLayout` the output is changed

```
"Layout Subviews"
"Layout Subviews" ---- because of initial settings 
"Animation block"
"Animation ended"
"Layout Subviews"
```

so i understand that animation block executed first and view updates, so animation block has higher priority than view's update in update cycle

is that right? If i was wrong, i want to understand relationship between view's update cycles and animation block

Comment: "when i changed layoutIfNeeded to setNeedsLayout the output is changed" If you change `layoutIfNeeded` to `setNeedsLayout`, you might as well just delete it entirely; it's the same thing. `layoutIfNeeded` means there _is_ an animation — we animate the act of layout. `setNeedsLayout` is just a random call; there is no animation here.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but still confused. `layoutIfNeeded` is trigger `layoutSubviews` directly (do not wait until update cycle). but animation blocks are triggered in update cycles, and animation block has `layoutIfNeeded`. I'm confused this relationships

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is inside the animation block, if it is animatable, does not run until animation time at the end of the transaction.

`layoutIfNeeded` counts as animatable. What it does in an animation block is: it causes the changes in frame etc. performed in code or by autolayout in `layoutSubviews` to be animated rather than immediate.

Basically, this is a way of wrapping the next layout moment in an animation.